# If is it possible to translate some exercises from german to english

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, languages

I want to ask if it is possible to publish a list of problems in German and this list to be translated because I don't know any word in German.

Comment: Have you tried google translate?

Comment: it is not useful.

Comment: Oof. That's a tough one. I think you should post a few problems at a time and see if you get good responses. Be sure to format and tag them appropriately.

Comment: Ahh. I see your post [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607250/translate-some-papers-from-german-to-english). Looks like Brian M. Scott translated that pretty well. I can see why they ignored that in the migration considerations. That is actually a really decent translation.

Comment: Why do you want these problems translated? It would certainly help to give some background and motivation.

Comment: "I don't know any word in German." I doubt that.

Answer (score 5):

There is a tag, [translation-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-request), intended [specifically for this purpose](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6689/propose-new-tag-translation-request).

To make such questions more acceptable (and avoid closure), I recommend that you post only one exercise per post, and (as mentioned in the comments above) you should provide some motivation for why you would like these exercises translated.

Answer (score 3):

If you post a few of the problems I would be willing to look at them.